# How to forward a request to a different route in Hapi (AKA "server redirect")?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

In NodeJS Hapi, how do I forward a route to another route, without an HTTP redirect?

For example, I want root request ('/') to get the index.html from my static routes handler. So `/` will get the same reply as `/public/index.html`.

Comment: AFAIK, server-side redirects are done with [`inject`](https://hapijs.com/api#serverinjectoptions-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there's no such functionality inside the handler function of a route.

The way to do this in Hapi is by using a [server extension](https://hapijs.com/api#serverextevents):

```
server.ext('onRequest', function (request, reply) {
    if (request.path == '/')
        request.setUrl('/public/index.html');
    return reply.continue();
});
```